# Error from simple_form when starting up the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I've cloned a project from GitHub, however when I try to run `rails server` it throws me an error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run rails server -h for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use rails generate simple_form:install to generate the Simple Form configuration.
Exiting
```

Then I try to run the installation of simple_form, but again, the same error appears

```
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use rails generate simple_form:install to generate the Simple Form configuration.
/home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
    from /home/andres/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
```

I'm using the version 3.2.0 of the gem on a Rails 4.2.4 installation, which could be causing the error?

Comment: Do you have a User class defined in your project ? In this case that might be User model. Can you paste the code here ?

Comment: The project doesn't even have models

Comment: Can you please paste the code thats throwing the error ?

Comment: Here are the errors than appear when [running rails server](https://gist.github.com/Oxyrus/4bd1d587ff8e85029b87) and when running [rails g simple_form:install](https://gist.github.com/Oxyrus/60b0506cc2648e83d47a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your Routes file. Possibly "devise_for :users"  line.

Were you trying to setup Devise and didn't set it up completely ? Seems like that

Check https://github.com/plataformatec/devise for documentation and setup instructions

Comment: It was the error, I commented the routes related to devise and now I can run the server, thanks!